# What type of test I shoud use between two samples to compare mean equal.?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I would do Wilcoxon rank sum test to compare mean equal. In R  `>wilcox.test(a, b)`
We can assume non-normality of the samples.

Comment: *Please* don't call the ***Wilcoxon*** rank sum test by the name "*Wilcox*". There's already more than one statistician called *Wilcox* / *Willcox* but they are not the right people to associate with the test. [Yes, I know R uses the command `wilcox.test` - but its help makes it quite clear that the test is *WIlcoxon*'s. It's a huge pity they did so, but that doesn't mean we are freed from the responsibility of correctly describing what we're doing]

Comment: Additionally, your question is not sufficiently clear in relation to the circumstances, nor what you want to know. - 1. Why are you using a Wilcoxon test?  2. We have many questions already that ask about the two sample t-test and the Wilcoxon (/Mann-Whitney); it is not at all clear that you are asking something new; please clarify what you seek that hasn't already been covered by answers on site. ... in relation to all of these comments, please edit to clarify your question, including incorporating any comments that explain what you meant to ask into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wilcoxon's test is a non-parametric alternative to the paired Student's t-test, is that what you want? Or do you want to compare the global mean? In which case you could use the Mann–Whitney U test.

Comment: Is Wilkox test evaluating the variance instead of the mean? So running t.test between both samples compares means? ´> t.test(a,b,var.equal=TRUE)

Comment: No, Wilcox compares the means using paired observations. `t.test(a,b,var.equal=TRUE)` is the standard parametric test which compares the global mean of each sample. A t-test would be appropriate If you assume normality of your data, which you probably shouldn't, since a plot of your data does not show normality, unless you have domain knowledge that this data really does come from a normal distribution.

Comment: Ok. Therefore, in this case, Mann-Whitney should run the best to test the means. But, what about to test equality of variances then?

Comment: You question asked about comparing the means. Do you also want to compare the variances? If so, are you trying to compare the distributions of the two samples (mean and variance together)?

Comment: Not actually, rather separate. Yes, I was wondering how to compare variances.

Comment: If the samples were normally distributed you could use an F-test, if they are not normally distributed however things get complicated. Personally I would not compare the variances.

Comment: Please see my comments under the question; they apply to your answer as well. The test being referred to by the question is the Mann-Whitney (1947), but is - reasonably - credited to Wilcoxon (1945). Mann and Whitney extended the tables to unequal sample sizes (and importantly gave a neat way to obtain the tables).

Answer (score 1):

What are the assumptions of the data? Are you assuming non-normality of the data? If so, non-parametric tests are appropriate. However, t-tests are appropriate if you believe the data has normality. If I recall precisely (hehe) there's a goodness of fit test to test for normality.